# How to preprocess training data on s3 without using notebooks for built-in algorithms

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I want to avoid using sagemaker notebook and preprocess data before training like simply changing the from csv to protobuf format as shown in the first link below for the built-in models.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-preprocess-data-transform.html

In the following example it explains preprocessing by using sklearn pipelines with the help of sagemaker python-sdk

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-using-amazon-sagemaker-inference-pipelines-and-scikit-learn/

What are the best practices if you just need to do format like changes and you don't need to use sklearn way of processing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use SageMaker Notebook instances to perform pre-processing or training. Notebooks are way to explore and carry out experiments. For production use cases, you can orchestrate tasks in a ML pipeline such as pre-processing, data preparation (feature engineering, format conversion etc.), model training and evaluation using AWS Step Functions. [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4686192/julien-simon) has covered it in his recent talk [here](https://youtu.be/dNb5jVffzPs).

You can explore using AWS Glue for pre-processing either using Python script (via Python Shell) or Apache Spark (Glue job). Refer this blog here for such use case
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/ensure-consistency-in-data-processing-code-between-training-and-inference-in-amazon-sagemaker/